# Removing colon from minicart Magento

Tags: magento

Im using Magento Community version 1.9

The header contains a minicart.

The label is: **cart: 0,00 DKK**

I have used inline translation to remove 'cart' so the result should be like: **0,00 DKK**, but I can't get rid of the colon.

thx in advance...

/Steen

Answer (score 0):

Use translation only to translate.

To customise you theme, edit the template file of the minicart:

```
app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/checkout/cart/minicart.phtml
```